# Jsp changes are not reflecting when deployed to a test environment linux tomcat. In Local it is working fine

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

Jsp changes are not reflecting when deployed to a test environment linux tomcat. In Local everything is working fine

Comment: This is incomplete question. Update your question with all required code snippets.

Comment: Check you're deploying to the correct context root.